# Resume uploads using samba

Tags: upload, samba, resume

I have been using the smbget command to resume downloads if there is a network dropout...
e.g.

```
smbget -r smb://mysambaserver/path/to/file
```

Is there an equivalent for "uploading" files?

Neither "`smbclient get`" nor "`smbcllient put`" appear to have a resume option.  I have checked google, but "smb put resume" appears just to list people uploading their resume!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent for uploading files, at least not as part of Samba itself.

Comment: I would have liked (a) someone to back you up, or (b) a proof somewhere by means of topic or link or specification.  Since it's easy to say "You can't".  Even a patch extension would have been nice.  But, after 6 months I guess I have to accept this is not possible. :-(

Comment: I'm the author of smbget, and one of the authors of smbclient.

Comment: Hi @jelmer I am trying to smbget over an ssh tunnel. I need to specifiy a different port but there is no option to do such a thing. can you help me ?

Comment: @mak: We should support port numbers in the URL, though I have never actually tried that code. Try something like smb://servername:1337/path/blah.